# How to download a pem file in php?

Tags: php

I have a public key stored in the variable `$pubKey`. I save this variable in a file.

```
file_put_contents('pubKey.pem', $pubKey);
```

I'm trying to allow users to download this file in their browser. Here's what I did:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/x-pem-file');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.pem"); 
readfile('pubKey.pem');
```

It managed to download the file. However, the downloaded file contains additional HTML tag. For eg, the `download.pem` file content is something like

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
<the public key content>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
   

    <div class="container">
           <some content of my webpage>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how I can remove all the html contents?

Comment: add in `ob_clean()` above the headers then wrap `exit(readfile('pubKey.pem'));` it looks like your using some templating logic around the file/controller which handles your above code, just need to not do that for that file/code/controller

Comment: That works, thank you so much for the help! Been stuck on this for quite a while :D

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Lawrence Cherone, changing the code to the following works:

```
ob_clean();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/x-pem-file');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.pem"); 
exit(readfile('pubKey.pem'));
```